# domdocument xpath grab the first tr anchor name and href without id or class

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Excuse my English.

I want to read the anchor name and href from the first "tr". The href I get, but not the name ...

Can someone help me?

```
$dom      = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($content2);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$xpath                   = new DOMXPath($dom);
$rows                    = $xpath->query('//tr');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    foreach ($cols as $col) {
        $test = $col->nodeValue;
        if ($xpath->evaluate('count(./a)', $col) > 0) { // check if an anchor exists
            $link = $xpath->evaluate('string(./a/@href)', $col); // if there is, then echo the href value
        }

    }
}

<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:20px;"><img src="images/gfx/programm.png" style="cursor: pointer;"> </td>
        <td style="width:415px;"><a href="?id=492488" onmouseover="Kurzinfo(492488)" onmouseout="hideit(492488)">Wondershare Filmora - 8.2.2.1 Patch</a> </td>
        <td nowrap="nowrap" style="text-align:right;">Appz </td>
        <td style="width:40px;text-align:right;">220 </td>
        <td style="width:20px;"> MB </td>
        <td style="width:150px;text-align:right;" nowrap="nowrap">21.05.2017 10:23:48 Uhr </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

Comment: What `name` are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want to get `Wondershare Filmora - 8.2.2.1 Patch`, for that you can use `text()`, i.e.:

```
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($content2);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$rows = $xpath->query('//tr');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    foreach ($cols as $col) {
        $test = $col->nodeValue;
        if ($xpath->evaluate('count(./a)', $col) > 0) { // check if an anchor exists
            $link = $xpath->evaluate('string(./a/@href)', $col); // get the href value
            $text = $xpath->evaluate('string(./a/text())', $col); // get the href text value
        }
    }
}
```

---

[PHP Demo](https://eval.in/802233)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to read the anchor name and href from the first "tr". The href I get, but not the name

The first `tr` can be expressed as `//table//tr[1]`. Similarly, the first anchor of the first `tr` can be fetched using `(//table//tr[1]/td//a)[1]` expression, e.g.:

```
$anchor_list = $xpath->query('(//table//tr[1]/td//a)[1]');
```

where `$anchor_list` is either instance of `DOMNodeList`, or `FALSE`. The elements (instances of `DOMElement`) can be accessed using the `[]` operator.

```
if ($anchor_list && $anchor_list->length) {
  $a = $anchor_list[0];
}
```

Having `DOMElement` we can easily access its attributes via `attributes` property:

```
$href = $a->attributes->getNamedItem('href');

var_dump($href ? $href->textContent : "(none)");
var_dump($name ? $name->textContent : "(none)");
```

If you want to get the inner text of the anchor node, use `textContent` property:

```
var_dump($a->textContent);
```